# Error after using simple git pull - 'preserve' a été remplacé par 'merges' fatal: valeur invalide pour 'pull.rebase' : 'preserve'

Tags: git

-After upgrading Git from 2.25 to 2.37 I have this error just after making a simple `git pull`

```
error: preserve : 'preserve' a été remplacé par 'merges' 
fatal: valeur invalide pour 'pull.rebase' : 'preserve'
```

-I try to downgrading to 2.35 to try to resolved but I have this error

```
sudo apt-get install git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.5 

[...] Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 git : Dépend: git-man (< 1:2.25.1-.) mais 1:2.37.1-0ppa1~ubuntu20.04.1 devra être installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

-So how can I make a simple git pull without error of preserve ? I use Ubuntu 20.04

tanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured `pull.rebase` to set it to the value `preserve`:

```
git config --global pull.rebase preserve
```

for instance (though you may not have used `--global`).  The `preserve` option was deprecated in Git version 2.25, with the advent of `git rebase --rebase-merges`; the new and improved option is spelled `merges` (or just `m`):

```
git config --global pull.rebase merges
```

Note that before you use either of these settings, you should become a Git Expert.  There are a lot of sharp edges here (though `--rebase-merges` is much less dangerous than `--preserve-merges`).